# AMC 12 2010B Problem Help #18

Tags: contest-math

Can someone explain this solution?
A frog makes 3 jumps, each exactly 1 meter long. The directions of the jumps are chosen independently at random. What is the probability that the frog's final position is no more than 1 meter from its starting position?

Solution 1

We will let the moves be complex numbers a,b , and c, each of magnitude one. The frog starts on the origin. It is relatively easy to show that exactly one element in the set

$$ {|a+b+c|,|a+b-c|,|a-b+c|,|a-b-c|} $$

has magnitude less than or equal to 1. Hence, the probability is 1/4.

Comment: Do we know how many jumps it makes?

Comment: I remember this question, it makes two jumps.

Comment: but in the answer it says a,b,c. Sure it isn't three?

Comment: Nevermind, I was right the first time, it's three jumps.

Comment: oops. so sorry, yes it is three

Comment: Can you put the link for read the original problem, and problem set?

Comment: http://wiki.artofproblemsolving.com/index.php/2010_AMC_12B_Problems/Problem_18   and then you can navigate the site for the entire problem set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funny that I remember this problem. Anyway this is how I solved it:

The frog starts at $(0, 0)$ and makes a jump, WLOG let it land at $(1, 0)$. From here, the frog can make two jumps and land anywhere on a circle of radius $2$ centered at $(1, 0)$, each point being equally likely. This has an area of $4 \pi$, and this circle is large enough so that it contains the entirety of the desired circle of radius $1$ centered at $(0, 0)$ that we want the frog to end up in. Thus, the probability is $\frac{\pi}{4\pi} = \frac{1}{4}$

As for the solution you linked, I don't know particularly what's troubling you about it so I'll explain as much as I can:

We choose at random three steps $a, b, c$. If exactly one element has absolute value (talking vector length here with complex numbers) less than or equal to $1$, then, out of $4$ possibilities, one will be inside the inner circle. So the probability is $\frac{1}{4}$.

How would you prove that exactly one is? Try considering whether it's possible to have more than one step which satisfies the conditions, and furthermore consider whether if none of them are. (This is pretty much the essence of the solution, so I don't want to just spoon feed it to you, especially since this is contest math)

Comment: but I wanna be spoon fed this time :[    ] feed me

Comment: The proof of why exactly one element has magnitude less than or equal to one is what stumps me.

Comment: Well, what you have in the set is all of the possible permutations of negative and positive signs (considering absolute value) of the three steps. Assuming it exists, consider the permutation that leads to an absolute value of less than or equal to 1. What would happen if you changed the sign of one of the steps?

Comment: Is there a nice proof that the sum of two unit vectors is uniformly distributed in the disc of radius 2?  There is clear radial symmetry, but I'm not sure that the distribution (conditional on lying on a particular radial line) is uniform.  In particular, if $\theta$ is uniform $[0,2\pi]$, I think the radial distribution is $2\cos \theta.$

Comment: @Aaron The sum of two uniform unit vectors is indeed not uniform in the disc of radius 2. The radius $R$ of the sum has as its CDF $\mathbb{P}(R \leq r) = 1-\frac{1}{\pi}\arccos\left(\frac{r^2-2}{2}\right)$ for $0 \leq r \leq 2$.